# How to map our data with Google Map data

Tags: data, google-maps, routing

I want to add all the bus route data and create a route finding app for my country since Google map has no data about bus routes in my country but with JavaScript API i could get the shortest path between two cities. e.g if i am going to D from A. it says from A to B then turn left go to C and then go to D likewise.

My idea is to get those points and i have my database with bus stops and route numbers, map the data and create my app. but the problem is the points which gives by Google map and the bus stops are not always the same. so i want to know whether there is a way in Google maps to add my bus stop data and bus route information along a particular road then i think it can easily be searched.

Thanks..

Comment: you can join the transit partner program - http://maps.google.com/help/maps/transit/partners/participate.html then you can gets your data on google maps

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered mapping the data on OpenStreetMap instead? They even may have your bus routes already mapped there.